# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-community_async-storage'

Tags: react-native, android-studio, asyncstorage

After installing AsyncStorage "yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage --save" Android Studio throw an exception ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21UVv.png))

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-community_async-storage'.
Unsupported BuildConfig type : Long
```

"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",

"react-native": "^0.63.1",

react-native-cli: 4.10.1

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hello @Viktor, You need to add more information. Which RN version are you using? How did you try to install it etc...

Comment: Hello @FreakyCoder, I've updated info.

Comment: Can you try: `npx jetify` and also please check that you have the proper local.properties file for Android.

Comment: @FreakyCoder I've already tried it http://i.imgur.com/SN3WzsI.png But it doesn't solve it.

Comment: local.properties http://i.imgur.com/Um0b0L4.png

Comment: Is this an old project? I've tried the AsyncStorage on a fresh project and it works well. Are you able to share the project with me?

Comment: Do you have these lines into the `settings.gradle` file:
```include ':@react-native-community_async-storage'
project(':@react-native-community_async-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android')
```

Comment: Yes I have: http://i.imgur.com/6lKNJEQ.png

Comment: Okay, last shoot :D Try to `Invalidate Cache & Restart` on Android Studio. If it does not work. I need to check it on code.

Comment: Also, please tell me that you've installed the async-storage with `npm i @react-native-community/react-native-async-storage` right? :D

Comment: I did this command "yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage --save".

Comment: Try the Invalidate Cache & Restart maybe it helps

Comment: And I'm already did Invalidate Cache & Restart on Android Studio

Comment: I will share you with project in few minutes.

Comment: Trying @Viktor Bondarenko

Comment: Hey again @Viktor, 
I've tested your project. You've upgraded the react-native version to the latest but your podfile and some of the files are old. 
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/
You need to change the PodFile and other stuff for upgrading it. I suggest you that open a fresh project and move your files to the new one. Upgrading is hell in React Native :(

Comment: @FreakyCoder, thank you very much! I'll try to create new project and move files there. :)

Comment: @FreakyCoder, I've initialized new project, it worked, but after installing "yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage --save" have the same problem http://i.imgur.com/JONSl2K.png. :(

Comment: The link to new project https://github.com/VikBn/AsyncTest

Comment: I will check it out asap

Comment: @FreakyCoder, problem solved in this issue https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/405    Thank's for help :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :) another Android problem